# IntelliJ IDEA - Facing issue in reading .class files

Tags: intellij-idea

Can’t read the .class files in IntelliJ. Class files just shows compiled code, code is not visible. I tried to download the sources, but its throwing an error “Cannot Download Sources, sources not found for: com.xxx.yyy:1.0.1”.But the files (source files/jar) are present in the specified path. Tried re-installing dependencies, still facing the same error. Please help!

Comment: Is the decompiler included in the community edition?

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @duffymo: I am using ultimate edition, its decompiled code.

Comment: it just shows as "
{ /* compiled code */ }
"